# Finding values which are not there in second dataframe and do arithmatic operation in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I have two dataframes, flat and bias. Bias has some missing values.
(2456650, 2459654). After subtracting bias from flat, I got the result for the remaining values. My task is to check for the nearest value in bias to do the subtraction for missing values.
I have to check for 2459654, which is a missing value in the bias, I have to check for (2459653 or 2459655). If they are not present, I have to check for (2459652 or 2459656) and subtract any value. I have to check for both + and -, unless I got one.

[flat_DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJbxA.png)

[Bias_DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjMc4.png)

[After subtracting the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INH3C.png)

But i hvae to check for values now which are not presnent in bias.

Comment: `flat[1].sub(flat[0].map(bias.set_index(0)[1]), fill_value=0)` (untested, but the general logic is there)

Comment: Sir as 2459650 is not available in bias I need to look for 2459650-1 or 2459650+1 in bias, whichever is available I need to map it for subtraction

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame constructors of `flat` and `bias`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qnil.png
these are the data with flat having duplicates

Comment: But we can't load an image in our python interpreter, [you need to provide DataFrame constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: sir can i provide u the csv?

Comment: https://mega.nz/folder/8xliEKqQ#ps8xfyPdwt62vFAWvN2McA

Comment: I have two dataframes flat and bias. Bias has some missing values
(2456650,2459654). After subtracting bias from flat I got the result for the remaining values. My task is to check for nearest value in bias to do the subtraction for missing values.
Like for 2459654 which is a missing value in bias I have to check for (2459653 or 2459655)  if they are not present i have to check for (2459652 or 2459656) and subtract with any value. I have to  check for both + and - unless I got one